# What does the end.method do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I've seen code like this:

```
def some_method
  # ...
end.another_method
```

What does the `end.another_method` part do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that your example is wrong, as what you are doing here is defining a method and calling a method on the result of a method definition (not a method call), which is always (usually?) `nil`.

There's a similar form which fmendez is referring to, but `end` is the end of a block, not a method definition in that case.

So, for example:

```
array.map do |element|
  element * element
end.sum
```

would, hypothetically, return a sum of squares of elements of given array.

But, if you are doing method chaining like this, it is more common to use bracket style blocks instead of `do..end`, so the above example would read:

```
array.map{ |element|
  element * element
}.sum
```

Blocks in Ruby are method arguments, not unlike any other method arguments (apart from the dedicated syntax), so putting dot after `end` is not different than putting the dot after `)` in

```
'hello'.concat(' world!').capitalize
```

Which is also an example of method chaining.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I was about to say that just now :-)

Comment: As far as I know, multiline blocks shouldn't be chained with either syntax.

Comment: Also, I get a `warning: void value expression` when dereferencing a method definition

Comment: @JanDvorak You certainly can. You can try this: a = [3,2,1]
a.map! do |element|
  element * element
end.sort!
p a

Comment: Just because they CAN doesn't mean they SHOULD :)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I don't see why one shouldn't chain methods with multiline blocks. I do it quite often. Regards the warning, which Ruby are you using and what do you get when you do `(def foo; end).class`?

Comment: @LoganSerman I agree with you. Chaining calls can make it a nightmare for testability. It can be hard to track down which method call in the chain is failing.

Comment: @fmendez: That's true, but that's true for any method chaining, not particularly those involving multiline blocks.

Comment: @MladenJablanović That's certainly true.

Comment: @MladenJablanović it returns `NilClass` with the warning `void value expression`

Comment: @MladenJablanović I'm using the jRuby 1.9.3 IRB console

Comment: I see... I would prefer if they elaborated. I myself prefer as little one-time variables as possible. Each to his own I guess. Anyway, Jörg came, the party's over... ;)

Answer (score 8):

In Ruby, the `.` is the *message sending operator*. (In other languages, it would be called a *method calling operator* instead.) So, when you say

```
foo.bar
```

it means "evaluate `foo` and send the message `bar` to the result of evaluating `foo`".

In this particular case, you are sending the message `another_method` to the result of evaluating

```
def some_method; end
```

The Ruby Language Specification says that the value of a method definition expression is undefined and should be ignored; and on most Ruby implementations, method definition expressions simply evaluate to `nil`, which isn't terribly useful.

However, on some implementations, method definition expressions *do* evaluate to something more useful than `nil`. On Rubinius, for example, they evaluate to the `CompiledMethod` object for the method being defined. And `CompiledMethod` has a rich API, so sending messages to a `CompiledMethod` object definitely makes sense.

It has also been proposed that method definition expressions should return a `Symbol` corresponding to the name of the method being defined or a `Method` object.

Put simply: the dot in this particular case means the exact same thing it always means in Ruby: send a message, call a method, invoke a member function, whatever you want to call it.

Comment: +1 nicely said! maybe you should mention that in general it's probably not a good idea to do this, as it's not portable between different Ruby implementations, as method definition usually returns nil.